# Size of array inside hash

Tags: perl

EDIT: Providing code as per demand from mppac:

I wanted the length of array inside hash.

Why is below showing undef?

```
$ >cat test.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Data::Dumper;

my %static_data_key = (
'NAME' =>['RAM','SHYAM','RAVI','HARI'],
);
print Dumper(\%static_data_key);

$ >./test.pl
$VAR1 = {
'NAME' => [
'RAM',
'SHYAM',
'RAVI',
'HARI'
]
};
```

Comment: Could you post code which can be run and demonstrates above behavior?

Comment: Where is the undef now?

Comment: It got sorted, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The return value of a Perl array in scalar context is the array's size.  For example:

```
my @array = ( 'a', 'b', 'c' );
my $size = @array;
print "$size\n";
```

This code will print '3'.  When dereferenced, anonymous arrays share this characteristic:

```
my $aref = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ];
print $aref, "\n";   # ARRAY(0x1e33148)... useless in this case.
my $size = @{$aref}; # Dereference $aref, in scalar context.
print "$size\n";     # 3
```

The code I'm demonstrating takes a few unnecessary steps to lend clarity.  Now consider this:

```
print scalar @{[ 'a', 'b', 'c']}, "\n";  # 3
```

Here we're constructing an anonymous array and immediately dereferencing it.  We obtain its return value in scalar context, which happens to be 3.

Finally, let's put that anonymous array into a hash:

```
my %hash = ( 
  NAME => [ 'joseph', 'frank', 'pete' ]
);

print scalar @{$hash{NAME}}, "\n";
```

Read that last line from the middle outward; first we obtain the value stored the `NAME` element within `%hash`.  That is a reference to an anonymous array.  So we dereference it with `@{ ..... }`.  And we use `scalar` to force scalar context.  The output is 3.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# your code goes here
use strict;
use warnings;
my %static_data_key = (
'NAME' =>['RAM','SHYAM','RAVI','HARI'],
);
print scalar @{$static_data_key{'NAME'}};
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/NvKmPb)